# I could not access Design View, menue bar and Navigation bar in microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently, when I open my MS access 2016 database, I could not find the regular view in microsoft access database that I used to see.

This is my ms access database:
[image]

As shown below (Number 1 and 2), I want to be able to see 1) the menue bar options and 2) the 2 tabs on the right lower side and the m in order to be able to change design (Design view). I do not have experience in vba.
I checked many posts (as holding shift tab while opening, pressing F11) but I could not find a solution.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there a "Run-Time" version of Access installed? Did you make the 2nd screenshot on a different computer then?

Comment: @braX Thx for your suggestions. The file is name is *.mdab  The second screenshot is from the web (not my computer files).  I did not change my MS access version that I used to work on but recently this happened!  I tried both suggestions below but problem persists. ANy more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Either press `Ctrl+F1`, or check that the file isn't named **.accdr* rather than **.accdb* .

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. The file is name is *.mdab  The second screenshot is from the web (not my computer files). I tried both but problem persists. ANy more suggestions?

Comment: `*.mdab` is a custom extension. Default is `*.mdb`. My guess is then - as @braX - that this "other computer" launches a run-time version of Access, not a full version. The run-time doesn't allow any design changes.

Comment: Thx  for the suggestions. That helps. The IT person fixed it here based on your suggestion . She unistalled some files from start menue>> settings>> Apps after closure of all microsoft ofice file. Appreciate that. Upvoted.